# How to intercept and manipulate a Internet Explorer showModalDialog with VBA

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, automation, modal-dialog

VBA is able to fill the data fields on the main page. By clicking (with VBA) on a button *Modify* the dialog is opened in a new window and it halts the execution of the VBA. Fields in the dialog page required to be adjusted (with VBA). The VBA resumes only after I manually close the dialog.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, we can't handle the popup modal (find the HTML elements and fill data) using VBA script. As an alternative workaround, I suggest you could try to use [Selenium IE WebDriver](https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/), by using it, we could not only find the web page elements and fill data, but also using the Switch To method to switch to the popup window, then using the FindElementById method to find the HTML elements and fill data.

Here are some related tutorials about how to use selenium webdriver, you could check it:

[Selenium 2.0 WebDriver with Visual Studio, C#, & IE – Getting Started](https://testguild.com/selenium-ie-visual-studio-c/)

[C# (CSharp) OpenQA.Selenium.IE InternetExplorerDriver Examples](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/OpenQA.Selenium.IE/InternetExplorerDriver/-/php-internetexplorerdriver-class-examples.html)

[How to Handle Multiple Browsers in Selenium CSharp](https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/c-sharp/how-to-handle-multiple-browsers-in-selenium-csharp/)